# Place error message inside a Bootstrap input

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a PHP that validates if a input is empty if it is an error message is displayed e.g Email required, I am using Bootstrap for my form. Originally the message is displayed under the input (which I don't want).

Code im currently using:

```
<label>Number Of Rooms: </label>                                            
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" max="10" name="Rooms" value="<?php echo $RoomErr;?>">
<span class="error">* <br><?php echo $RoomErr;?></span>
```

here is the link to the website [website](https://tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/lest-sidebar.php)

I want to display the error message inside the text input i tried assigning the error to the value of the input:

```
<label>Number Of Rooms: </label>                                            
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm error" max="10" name="Rooms" value="<?php echo $RoomErr;?>">
```

The following does not work.

My CSS just assigns the error to color red

```
.error{
color:red;
}
```

I can't find much stuff about this.

Comment: add the class `error` to your input as `class="form-control input-sm error"`

Comment: Raushan is right <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm error">

Comment: I have added it but the error is not displaying isnide the input still.

Comment: Please show validation js here

Comment: I am using php to validate this and it works, the error is displaying under the input as expected i just want to move it into the input rather than displaying it under it

Comment: You can try like this <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm error" max="10" name="Rooms" placeholder="<?php echo $RoomErr;?>">

Comment: Thats working now. you should add it as a answer,

Comment: If you like than plz accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this, because it is working as a placeholder.

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm error" max="10" name="Rooms" placeholder="<?php echo $RoomErr;?>">
```

Comment: But, now the message is inside but its not red what could be the problem?

Comment: because placeholder is not has class

Comment: this is the link for help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864832/how-to-change-placeholder-color-of-specific-input-field?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I am using position:absolute; And manage this

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 135px;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
.form-group .error {
    left: 165px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
}
.form-group{position:relative;}
.form-inline .form-control{display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;}
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-md-9">

         <div class="container-form">
         <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
         <form id="EmailForm" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
         
         <div class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group" style="position: relative;">
         <label for="first_name">Name: </label>
         <input class="form-control input-sm" name="first_name" type="text">
         <span class="error">*Name is required</span>
       </div>
      </div>
         <div class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="last_name">SurnameName: </label>
           <input class="form-control input-sm" name="last_name" type="text">
           <span class="error">*</span>
          </div>
          </div>
         <div class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email: </label>
          <input class="form-control input-sm" name="email" type="text">
          <span class="error">* Email is required</span>
          
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label>Number Of Rooms: </label>           
          <input class="form-control input-sm" max="10" name="Rooms" value="Mininum number of Hours : 3" type="number">
          <span class="error">* Mininum number of Hours : 3</span>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label> Number hours: </label>
          <input class="form-control input-sm" min="3" name="Hours" type="number">
          <span class="error">* Mininum number of Hours : 3</span>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group">        
         <label for="description">Description of the House: </label> 
         <textarea name="description" rows="auto" class="form-control input-sm" cols="55"></textarea>
         <span class="error">* Description is required</span>
         </div>
         </div>
          <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="radio" style="margin-left:70px">         
          <input name="ironing" id="radiobtn" value="Yes" type="radio">
          Yes          
         </div>          
          <div class="radio">         
          <input name="ironing" id="radiobtn" value="No" type="radio">
          No          
          </div>
          <span class="error">* Ironing is Required</span>
          <span class="help-block" style="margin-left:50px">Would Like Ironing?</span>
          </div>
         </div>
         <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
         </form>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: @ChandraShekhar its not.. the error is displaying all over the place.