# how to customize placeholder in only one place of the site

Tags: html, css

How can I change the placeholder color without changing other placeholder on the site?

My code

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="form.username" id="Login" placeholder="LOGIN">
```

Comment: The answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864832/how-to-change-placeholder-color-of-specific-input-field) is what you want

Comment: thanks Alejandro Teixeira Mu ,this topic help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your question: I think you have to reference something (a tag or a css class) that lays "around" the placeholder in question. What is unique about the part of your site the placeholder in? Take this unique point as the selector and reference your css styling according to this point.

But according to your code: Just add a class="classname" to your tag with a classname of your choice. Then specify the attributes in your css file for the classname.

Hope this helps?

Comment: hello,thanks your answer on topic
//css
::placeholder
color:red;
}

this css change placeholder texto color,ok but change in all site,where use "placeholder" ,I want to change only the code that I posted in the topic

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to style your input fields. Maybe try to wrap the input field in a parent div to make it unique.

HTML:

```
<div id="Login">
  <input type="text" ng-model="form.username"  placeholder="LOGIN">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Login input[type=text]  {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  boder-color: yellow;
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: this dont change "placeholder"

Comment: I updated the answer. This should help.