# How to do CSS customization in ejs-dropdownlist in Angular

Tags: css, angular, drop-down-menu, ejs

```html
<ejs-dropdownlist [dataSource]='data' placeholder='Search Fields' class="ejs-dropdownlist">
</ejs-dropdownlist>
```

this is my html tag and I want the placeholder to have font-size 15 and color grey.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do these kind of process, open developer console and inspect to element find class name of element. Then in style.css write the css code. For library element component.css does't work. You need to use style.css

```
select .e-input::placeholder {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
select .e-input::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
select .e-input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
```

Comment: It can be done in component.css as well. Your answer worked for me. Thank you!


**.ejs-dropdownlist{
    input {
        width: 90%;
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #757575;
    }
}**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
select + input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}

select + input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}

select + input::placeholder {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
```

But here you can find something similar: [How to change placeholder color of specific input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33864971/4477946)